# Why? NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context

Tags: ios, reactjs, share, navigator

Full error: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.

Why I got first time, but not second when **sharing file**?

```js
const shareData = {
  files: [
    new File([buffer], `${imgId}.mp4`, {
      type: "video/mp4",
    }),
  ],
  title: "Megosztom",
  text: "Mentsd le a képekbe, és oszd meg storyban.",
};
```

```js
navigator
  .share(shareData)
  .then(() => {
    log(
      {
        text: `'The share was successful 1 ` + getTempUserShortId(),
      },
      env
    );
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    log(
      {
        text: `There was an error sharing 1 ${error} ` + getTempUserShortId(),
      },
      env
    );
  });
```